# SSIS Flat file destination export multi-line column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids, flat-file

I have a SQL table as Source and I want to export it's contents to a Flat file using SSIS.

Simplified example:

```
Source: Notes table (CreatedBy, Description, CreatedOn)
The Description field is nText.

Destination: Flat file - Fixed length 
CreatedBy(0-50)
Description (51-250)
CreatedOn (251-270)
```

The problem is that the description can be really long and we don't want it to be truncated after `200` chars. It should wrap to the next line.

I cannot find a way to do this using SSIS.

Really appreciate your help.

**Update**

I am looking to achieve a layout like below:

```
CreatedBy | Description                          | CreatedOn|
John        Really long description..............  2/2/2017
            more text..
John2       This is the second line                2/3/2017
```

Hadi answer allows to break a long string into parts but still doesn't solve the layout problem.

Comment: the answer provided worked 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow these steps:

1. In The `DataFlow Task`add s script component between the `OLEDB Source` and `Flat File Destination`
2. In the `Script Component` Mark `Description` Column as Input, Add `OutDescription` Column as Output Column of type `DT_WSTR` and length `200`
3. In the `Script` window write the following code (Inside `Input0_RowProcessing` Method:

   ```
   If Not Row.Description_IsNull AndAlso 
      Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Description.Trim) Then

          If Row.Description.Trim.Length > 200 Then

               Dim LongString As String = Row.Description.Trim

               Dim longlist As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

               Dim idx As Integer = 0

               While idx <= LongString.Length

                   If LongString.Length < idx + 200 Then
                       longlist.Add(LongString.Substring(idx))
                   Else
                       longlist.Add(LongString.Substring(idx, 200))
                   End If



                   idx += 200

               End While

               Row.OutDescription = String.Join(vbNewLine & "".PadLeft(50,CChar(" ")), longlist)

          Else

              Row.OutDescription = Row.Description

           End If

   Else


       Row.OutDescription_IsNull = True


   End IF
   ```
4. In `Flat File Destination` map the `OutDesciption` column instead of `Description` column

Comment: I am a bit new to this, but this code looks like it is going to only fetch a substring of length 200, which is the same as truncation.

Comment: oooh. i missunderstood the question. i will fixed it

Comment: Hadi, I tried your code. It adds line breaks to the string but the new line for starts from 0 index and not 51. I want the description column to be wrapped in it's own space (e.g. 51-250). But your answer gave me a direction and a way to approach this problem. Updated the question with a sample layout.

Comment: @AmanvirSinghMundra Just use `String.Join(vbNewLine & "".PadLeft(50,CChar(" ")), longlist)` i updated my answer

Comment: Padding doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am missing something in the configuration. I'll try to get it working and then mark it as an answer. Thanks a lot for the help :)